# How to exclude records from second table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Still a Rails newbie. Code would be great, but also any suggestions on what to search/where to learn what I need, as I'm sure the answer is out there but I'm not sure what I should search on.

I'm trying to create a site similar to taskrabbit or upwork, where a member can post a job and a worker can submit a bid on the job. The issue I have is when a person bids on a job, I don't want that job to show up in the list of jobs that the worker can bid on.

I have two tables, a "jobs" table and a "bids" table. The tables both have a "job_id" field. The bids table has a worker_id field that is the id of the worker that submitted a bid on the job. What I'd like is to get a result set of jobs that doesn't include jobs where there is a bid that has a particular worker_id.

Models are as follows:

```
class Worker < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bids
end

class Bid < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :worker
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bids
end
```

Comment: Please add your Models with associations to your question

Comment: @jvillian models added per your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can change your `Worker` to include `jobs` like this:

```
class Worker < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bids
  has_many :jobs, through: :bids
end
```

Then, to get all the `jobs` that a `worker` has not yet bid on:

```
Job.where.not(id: @worker.jobs)
```

As David Weber says, you could make this a method on `Job`, something like:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bids

  class << self

    def available_for(worker)
      where.not(id: worker.jobs)
    end

  end
end
```

In which case, you would use it something like:

```
Job.available_for(@worker)
```

David Weber in fact said you could make it a `scope`. I will note that the [official Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) states:

> Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes.

You could write that class method as:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bids

  def self.available_for(worker)
    where.not(id: worker.jobs)
  end

end
```

There are some different opinions on which is the better way. My view is that it is a matter of personal preference.

I will also note that [Jörg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%c3%b6rg-w-mittag) wishes to state:

> I am one of those Ruby Purists who likes to point out that there is no such thing as a class method in Ruby. I am perfectly fine, though, with using the term *class method* colloquially, **as long as it is fully understood by all parties that it is a colloquial usage**. In other words, if you *know* that there is no such thing as a class method and that the term "class method" is just short for "instance method of the singleton class of an object that is an instance of `Class`", then there is no problem. But otherwise, I have only seen it obstruct understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a scope. A user can't see all jobs, they can only see `available_jobs`

Then define it for them. 
`available_jobs = Job.where.not(Bid.where(user_id: current_user.id).select(job_id))`

Or something more logical. Setting up a scope would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<%= link_to "bid on this job", 
job_path(@job) unless current_user.job_id == @job? %>
```

Simply won't show as a link if already bid (I think!)

Or you could show the job and if the current_user already bid you can link to show his bid instead of bid/new Up to you whether you want to allow the person to change the bid.